# GridView Updating from code behind throwing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updating

I have a GridView with a list of clients and their details bound to a Sq1DataSource. I want to update it from code behind thru the RowUpdating event, by accessing data cell by cell and sending it to an Update function in my Client BLL. This is the code:

```
   protected void gvClients_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow row = gvClients.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        //accesses Client Id
        cliIdStr = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
        int cliId = int.Parse(cliIdStr);
        cliBll = new ClientBLL(conStrName);
        //Accesses client object from DB according to Client Id accessed from gridView
        client = cliBll.GetClient(cliId);
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.ClientName = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
            client.Phone = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
            client.EMail = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text;
            client.Fax = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[5].Controls[0])).Text;
            client.Address = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[6].Controls[0])).Text;
            client.City = ((DropDownList)(row.Cells[7].Controls[0])).SelectedValue;
            client.ZipCode = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[8].Controls[0])).Text;
            client.IdNum = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[9].Controls[0])).Text;
            client.BusField = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[10].Controls[0])).Text;
            cliBll = new ClientBLL(conStrName);
            cliBll.UpdateClient(cliDtlShrt);
        }
    }
```

When I run the program and press the edit button of the GridView everything is fine but when I press the Uodate button the following exception is thrown:

> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range
>   of valid values. Parameter name: index]
>   System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +8673806

pointing to this line in the code:

```
cliIdStr = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
```

If I understand the message correctly the problem is in the Controls[0], but why? How can I access data from the gridView cells in order to send to Updating?

Comment: Are you sure there is an actual TextBox control in the cell? Did you put it in there yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails because when update occurs the row offering edit UI is no longer available - the row at `e.RowIndex` is a normal grid-view row whose cells will have control as per column type. So, most of cells (e.g. cells for BoundField column) will not have any control inside it as the cell directly contains the value - hence the error at `Controls[0]`.

You need to use [GridViewUpdateEventArgs.NewValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) property to get the new values for the row (non-key columns). Similarly values for key columns will be present in [e.Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.keys.aspx).

EDIT: I will also suggest that you consider using `ObjectDataSource` instead of `SqlDataSource` to make your life simpler - see [this article](http://www.vinull.com/Post/2007/04/16/aspnet-gridview-and-objectdatasource-wi.aspx) to get you started.

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised at what you wrote that the row offering edit UI is no longer available, because I coppied the code from the msdn GridView.RowEditing Event article. I will try your answer and I will also look up the article you suggested.

Comment: I didn"t succeed in getting the value from e.Keys. How is that done? Thank you.

Comment: @Dov, `RowEditing` happens when you click on edit and grid-view offers the row with edit UI. The purpose of event is to do any kind adjustment to edit UI - for example, you might want to fill drop-down with some specific values etc. `RowUpdating` happens when you click save/update in edit mode, so gridview switches back to normal view.

Comment: In the article I mentioned there's a RowUpdating event coded as I wrote!